# Get Invalid use of default parameter using adInteger

Tags: sql, parameters, asp-classic, adodb

I have a problem with this statement. for some reason I get the error: Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid use of default parameter 
The statement work fine until the last parameter where it is suppose to add an integer to the SQL statement. If I comment out the last parameter the statement works fine but for some reason it crashes when the last statement is add.  I hope someone can tell me why it tells me that this is an invalid use of default parameter.  I have tried every combination I can come up with. I have check and it is not null, I have hard coded a value in for the variable and still get the same error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = tadsdb

cmd.CommandText = "insert into poc_data (poc_userid, POC_FNAME,POC_LNAME, POC_EMAIL, POC_ORG, DSN_PHONE, DSN_FAX, POC_TYPE_ID,UNIT_ID) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@new_id",adVarChar,,50,new_id)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@first_name",adVarChar,,50,first_name)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@last_name",advarchar,,50,last_name)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@email",adVarChar,,50,email)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@organization",adVarChar,,50,organization)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@dsn_phone",adVarChar,,50,dsn_phone)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@dsn_fax",advarchar,,50,dsn_fax)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@user_type",advarchar,,50,user_type)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@unit_id",adInteger,,unit_id)
    'cmd.Parameters.Append 
    cmd.Execute
    set cmd = Nothing
```

Comment: You're missing an extra comma before specifying `unit_id`. At the moment the `unit_id` is being set as the size argument not the value.

Comment: That works thanks.  I was going blind trying to figure it out.